# Synchronization for inverse view of synchronized BiMap

Tags: java, guava, bimap

The `Maps.synchronizedBiMap()` method states that

> it is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map
>   when accessing any of its collection views.

Does this include the `inverse()` view of the BiMap? For example, if the variables are initialized as in the following example, can invoking `inverse.put()` from other threads be problematic (e.g. the change is not visible in a `get()` call on either `map` or `inverse`, even if `put` *happened-before* `get`)?

```
BiMap<Object, Object> map = Maps.synchronizedBiMap(HashBiMap.create());
BiMap<Object, Object> inverse = map.inverse();
```

If this is in fact a problem, is there a standard/recommended way of solving this?

// EDIT

Looking at the implementation, it seems like the `inverse()` of a `SynchronizedBiMap` is also a `SynchronizedBiMap`, sharing the same `mutex`. Does this mean the described problem is non-existent? Confirmation from a Guava Collections expert would be much appreciated ;)

Comment: The described problem is apparent from the example that follows the sentence you quoted: when iterating  (or doing any sequence of operations) on a view, you need to synchronize, on the synchronized BiMap, the whole iteration (or sequence) in order to have deterministic behavior.

Comment: As with all the views, manual synchronization is only required when doing iteration, and it's required when iterating over the inverse as well.  You don't have to synchronize e.g. keySet.contains either.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If you want to iterate over the inverse, should you synchronize on the inverse map or the original map?

Comment: Synchronize on the original map.  The original map is the mutex for itself and all its views, including the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

No, in this case you don't have to synchronize on inversed map. You cited only a fragment of the documentation, I'll also switch original `keySet()` with `inverse()` in the example code:

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) bimap backed by the specified bimap. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing bimap is accomplished through the returned bimap.
>
> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when accessing any of its collection views:
>
> ```
> BiMap<Long, String> map = Maps.synchronizedBiMap(
>     HashBiMap.<Long, String>create());
> //...
> BiMap<String, Long> inverse = map.inverse();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
> Set<String> set = inverse.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
> //...
> synchronized (map) {  // Synchronizing on map, not set!
>   Iterator<String> it = set.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>   while (it.hasNext()) {
>     foo(it.next());
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

So when you want a deterministic behavior during iteration over its views (which includes in iterating over inverse view), you have to synchronize on your instance.

In case of `.inverse()`, as you mentioned, [it creates new synchronized bimap using same mutex object](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v21.0/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Synchronized.java#L1340), so it synchronizes properly on methods like `get` or `contains`.

Comment: You claim that synchronization gets you deterministic order, and if you don't need deterministic order you don't need synchronization.  But that's not what the documentation says.  It says non-deterministic _behavior,_ which can include [throwing random exceptions](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).  You absolutely must synchronize if you want to iterate at all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Fair enough, thanks for correction. I've edited my answer.